# go on to+verb sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I was practicing with a key word transformation exercise and then I found the following phrasal verb:
went on to become

the full sentence is the following one:

> she went on to become a successful business woman

My question is: what does the phrasal verb exactly mean ( if that can be considered a phrasal verb ) ?
Could you please give me a few examples about this verb's usage?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just goggle **go on to**: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-on-to-do

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand the example sentence you gave to make the explanation easier:

> *"She graduated from New York University a few years ago. She **went on to** become a successful business woman."*

The phrase "*went on to*" implies here that *after she graduated* from college, she *later* became a successful business woman. In general, "*after she did X, she went on to do Y*" it is basically just a way of saying "*after she did X, she did Y*".

However, this construct is not only used in reference to people. For example:

> *The book began by with an overview of basic English grammar. **It then went on to** discuss English internet slang.*

Here, it is used to refer to the arrangement of a book's contents, rather than the actions/experiences of a person. But the pattern is basically the same. It's essentially just saying "first the book discussed X, then it discussed Y".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The original sentence of the exercise ( the sentence to transform ) was
the following one :
 In the future she became a successful business woman.
The " word " given was ' went ' .
Does the rule still apply in this case?
Sorry if the question sounds dumb...